# Scrolling down to find element with text not working in android emulator

Tags: java, selenium, android-emulator, appium

I am using Appium desktop server (v 1.15) along with java-client as 7.3.0 and selenium-server 3.141.59.

In my android emulator, I need to scroll down to view a text and stop the scrolling once the text is found.
I tried using the following :

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\""+text+"\"));");

driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textMatches(\"" + containedText + "\").instance(0))"));

where driver is AndroidDriver<MobileElement>
```

The issue I am facing is that the scrolling does not stop even if the text is correctly found.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom scroll method i use:

```
public void scroll(MobileElement anchorElement, double startPointOffsetPercentage, double endpointOffsetPercentage) {
    //Determines the type of driver used for the gesture (i.e. AndroidDriver, iOSDriver, etc) 
    TouchAction scroll = new TouchAction((MobileDriver) anchorElement.getWrappedDriver());

    //Gets your anchor element size to use as reference for the scroll
    Dimension size = anchorElement.getSize();
    int anchor = anchorElement.getCenter().getX();
    int startPoint = (int) (size.height * startPointOffsetPercentage);
    int endPoint = (int) (size.height * endpointOffsetPercentage);

    //Performs the gesture using your anchor element as reference for the action,the start and end offsets as the amount to scroll. Duration can be set to smaller to flick instead of scroll. 
    scroll.press(PointOption.point(anchor, startPoint)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(2))).moveTo(PointOption.point(anchor, endPoint)).release().perform();

}
```

I use this as a "scroll to element" custom method:

```
 public void scrollToElement(String elementId, MobileElement scrollableElement) {
    MobileDriver driver = (MobileDriver) scrollableElement.getWrappedDriver();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            if (driver.findElements(By.id(elementId)).isEmpty() || !driver.findElement(By.id(elementId)).isDisplayed()) {
                scroll(scrollableElement, 0.5, 0.1);
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ignored) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following by using the resource-id instead of scrollable(true) as it is not for all cases, resource-id should be the id of a parent element of the one you want to scroll to:

```
    driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
                "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.androidsample.generalstore:id/rvProductList\")).scrollIntoView(text(\""+ item + "\"));"));
```